# Parabola arc length minimization

Tags: optimization, conic-sections, arc-length

Consider a parabola: $y = a x^2 + b x + c$. I want that parabola to have the vertex on the $x=0$ axis (so $b = 0$), to be downward concave (so $a<0$) and to pass through the point $(r,h)$ with $r$ and $h$ both positive. If $x=s$ is the point where the parabola intersect the $y=0$ axis, is it possible to find the value of $s$ (as a closed form function of $r$ and $h$) that minimize the length of the parabolic arc in $0<x<s$?

Comment: Your equation $y= a x^2 + c$ has two variables to find: $a$ and $c$, so you need two equations. The first is obviously $h = a r^2 + c$, while the second can be get from the formula for getting arc length. So, if your curve is defined as $y=f(x)$, the the length of arc between $x=x_1$ and $x=x_2$ is $\int_{x_1}^{x_2} \sqrt{1 + f'(x)}dx$. So you need to find a function that describes arc length and then find zeroes of its derivative to minimize its length

Comment: That was clear; the point is: the equation you get integrating and then deriving can be solved in closed form?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $(r,h)$ is fixed, you'll find that the parabola satisfying those conditions has the formula

$$ y = h\frac{s^2-x^2}{s^2-r^2} $$

The arc length in $(0,s)$ is given by

$$ L(s) = \int_0^s \sqrt{(y')^2+1}\ dx = \int_0^s \sqrt{\left(\frac{-2hx}{s^2-r^2}\right)^2+1}\ dx $$

Let $t = \frac{s^2-r^2}{2h}$, this becomes a [common integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_irrational_functions#Integrals_involving_r_=_%E2%88%9Aa2_+_x2)

\begin{align} L(s) &= \frac{1}{t} \int_0^s \sqrt{x^2+t^2}\ dx \\
&= \frac{1}{2t}\left( x\sqrt{x^2+t^2} + t^2\ln \Big(x + \sqrt{x^2+t^2}\Big) \right)\bigg|_0^s \\
&= \cdots \end{align}

Once you have $L(s)$, it remains to solve $L'(s)=0$. There might not be a closed form solution.

Comment: Would not it be easier to calculate the integral first?

Comment: You're right. I got distracted by too many constants.

Comment: Regardless, the equation will be very complicated